# Scatter graph coming out wrong

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to create my scatter graph containing two different data’s, however I do not know what I am doing wrong as the graph is coming out completely wrong. This is what I coded:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

conflict_rate <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/owid-datasets/master/datasets/Conflict%20deaths%20by%20country%20%E2%80%93%20UCDP%20(2019)/Conflict%20deaths%20by%20country%20%E2%80%93%20UCDP%20(2019).csv")

colnames(conflict_rate)[colnames(conflict_rate) == "Violent deaths in conflicts and one-sided violence(UCDP 2019))"] <- "Deaths_in_conflict"jointdata <- inner_join(data,conflict_rate, by = c("Entity", "Year"))

colnames(jointdata)[colnames(jointdata) == "Corruption.Perception.Index..Transparency.International..2016.."] <- "TICPI"

ggplot(jointdata, aes(x = "Violent deaths in conflicts and one-sided violence (UCDP 2019)", y = TICPI)) +  geom_point() +  
labs(title = "Violent deaths vs Corruption perception",    
x = "Violent deaths in conflicts and one-sided violence (UCDP 2019)",  y = "Corruption Perception Index (Transparency International 2016)")
```

I was expecting my scatter graph to look right from what I coded, however the points all seem to be in a straight verticals line going down the middle of the graph with no x axis points.

Comment: Use the backtick ``` to capture names of variables that have spaces, not quotation marks.

Comment: Generally, I'd suggest keeping column names short and simple, perhaps `deaths` would be good here, and then you can rely only on `labs()` to provide the longer name for an axis title.

Comment: You have changed your column names, so use `ggplot(jointdata, aes(x = Deaths_in_conflict, y = TICPI)) + geom_point()`. Your code isn't reproducible though, since we don't have `data`.

Comment: "Violent deaths in conflicts and one-sided violence(UCDP 2019))" lacks one of the spaces in "Violent deaths in conflicts and one-sided violence (UCDP 2019)", so ggplot is using that text as the x axis data instead of the variable with a very similar name.   I suggest using short, easy variable names and then using `scale_x_continuous(name = "Put your long name here")` or `labs(x = "Put your long name here")` to control the labeling of the axis.